# Database not updated with module

Tags: magento2, module, database

I've downloaded the .zip of a module (for a slider), extracted it and ran setup:upgrade.

I can see the module through the backend, but when I go to the page to main page I have this error :

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table
>   'magento.sy_slider' doesn't exist, query was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM
>   sy_slider AS main_table

I tried many thing to update the database, but nothing changed.

Comment: The issue is, table which need to create while instalaling extension is not created.

Comment: Can you check your setup file if the code for table creation is there or not?

Answer (score 4):

You need to try re-install extension with this steps.

1. Identify Magento 2 extension name, you can get name from `registration.php`.
2. Remove extension entry from `app/etc/config.php` (entry identify from step1)
3. Remove extension entry from `setup_module` table in magento database. (entry identify from step1)
4. After remove the things, please also run these commands.

   ```
   php bin/magento cache:clean
   php bin/magento cache:flush
   php bin/magento indexer:reindex
   php bin/magento setup:upgrade
   php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
   ```

Comment: I did that. I didn't work. But I insisted and it worked